# Android: LayoutParams does not accept float value

Tags: java, android, android-layout

why

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1/11);
```

does not work but

```
String s =  "0.0909";
float fVal = Float.valueOf(s).floatValue();

TableRow.LayoutParams layout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, fVal);
```

does?

I use this to make table rows fit in a table with dynamic table width.

Regards

Comment: Easy, easy my friend ;-). Just look at my questions and you will see that some of them are not answered or answered in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/11` is an int (which happens to be 0), because both `1` and `11` are integers.

Try `1.0f / 11` instead to get a float value (or `1f / 11` but I find it less readable).